# Pivotear columnas

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transact-sql, mssql

Tengo una tabla con asientos contables que tienen el campo "importe" y las columnas cuentas debe y haber:

| Cuenta Debe | Cuenta Haber | Importe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| caja y banco | Compras | 100 |
| Impuestos | Gastos | 21 |

Estoy intentando hacer pivotear la columna de cuentas de forma que el importe me quede separado en debe y haber y las filas sean las distintas cuentas.
Ejemplo:

| Cuenta. | Debe | Haber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| caja y banco | 100 | 0 |
| Compras | 0 | 100 |
| Impuestos. | 21 | 0 |
| Gastos | 0 | 21 |

Actualmente estoy usando un Union All pero no creo que sea la mejor opcion, y me tarda mucho en cargar cuando son muchos asientos, a su vez me cuesta ordenarlos.

```
 SELECT
idcontaasiento,subctasd.Des as 'Cuenta',
sum(Imp) as Debe, 0 as Haber
 from CONTAASIENTOS asient
left join CONTASUBCUENTAS subctasd 
on asient.IdContaSubCuentaDeb = subctasd.IdContaSubCuenta 
left join CONTASUBCUENTAS subctash
on asient.IdContaSubCuentaHab = subctash.IdContaSubCuenta 
where IdContaAsiento in (5159752)
group by idcontaasiento,subctasd.Des,subctash.Des
            
UNION ALL 
        
SELECT 
idcontaasiento,subctash.Des as 'Cuenta', 0 as 'Debe',sum(Imp) as 'Haber'
from CONTAASIENTOS asient
left join CONTASUBCUENTAS subctasd
on asient.IdContaSubCuentaDeb = subctasd.IdContaSubCuenta 
left join CONTASUBCUENTAS subctash
on asient.IdContaSubCuentaHab = subctash.IdContaSubCuenta 
where IdContaAsiento in (5159752)
group by idcontaasiento,subctash.Des,subctasd.Des
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo de tu código no se te puede ayudar, vuelve cuando hayas intentado algo y entonces te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Y al menos pon la estructura de la tabla. Para solucionarlo estaría bien hacer referencia al id de cada asiento y por supuesto los nombres de cada columna que ya nos avanzas.

Comment: Perdon, ahi agregue lo que estoy haciendo actualmente. No es lo mas optimo.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con MySQL o SQL Server? Son dos productos distintos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que planteas parece algo así:

```
SELECT IdContaSubCuentaDeb Cuenta,Imp Debe,0 Haber 
  FROM contaasientos
UNION ALL
SELECT IdContaSubCuentaHab Cuenta,0 Debe,Imp Haber 
  FROM contaasientos;
```

Que puedes comprobar a través del siguiente dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE contaasientos(
  idcontaasiento int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  IdContaSubCuentaDeb varchar(15),
  IdContaSubCuentaHab varchar(15),
  Imp float
  );
INSERT INTO contaasientos (
    IdContaSubCuentaDeb, IdContaSubCuentaHab, Imp
  ) VALUES
('caja y banco','Compras',100),
('Impuestos','Gastos',21);
```

Con los siguientes datos:

```
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| idcontaasiento | IdContaSubCuentaDeb | IdContaSubCuentaHab | Imp  |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|              1 | caja y banco        | Compras             |  100 |
|              2 | Impuestos           | Gastos              |   21 |
+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+

+--------------+------+-------+
| Cuenta       | Debe | Haber |
+--------------+------+-------+
| caja y banco |  100 |     0 |
| Impuestos    |   21 |     0 |
| Compras      |    0 |   100 |
| Gastos       |    0 |    21 |
+--------------+------+-------+
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Básicamente el código que puso en la pregunta pero sin tomar en cuenta las tablas que incluyó en el código.

Comment: Hola, @LuisCazares Si te fijas, el OP está haciendo un `GROUP BY` que yo no hago y la consulta que propongo da el resultado que pide a partir del ejemplo que proporciona. A veces el error está en poner cosas de más, no veo qué tiene de malo mi respuesta. Si crees que puede mejorarse, estoy abierto a tus sugerencias.

Comment: Lo malo de tu respuesta es que no toma en cuenta todos los datos que se dieron. Tampoco toma en cuenta la posibilidad de que se quiera tener solo una fila por cuenta. Al final de cuentas, no soluciona el problema y es posible que termine por generar un mayor problema (sin agrupación hay más datos y por lo tanto tarda más en mostrar la información).

Comment: @LuisCazares O también puede resolver la duda al simplificar una cuestión que podría estar desbordándolo. Para eso interactuamos con el OP, dejemos que hable y complete la pregunta con los datos y ejemplos que conduzcan al resultado que requiera. En principio, con mi respuesta obtiene lo que ha pedido, en el SQL de su intento puede poner mil cosas. Por ejemplo, agrupar por cada asiento no termina de convencerme, el `WHERE` no tengo muy claro por qué lo pone...